Issue with Lenis smooth scroll triggering with horizontal scroll setup
I am currently working on implementing the Lenis plugin for smooth scroll to my project, but stumping to some issues to get it work. where I need horizontal smooth scrolling.
The concept
I am trying to achieve a horizontal slider with gallery images next to each other. The slider is overflow and to navigate through the gallery, users have to scroll down or up to slide left or right in the gallery. Like we familiar of on basically all websites.
To make it feel more smooth, I would like to use the Lenis smooth scroll plugin from Darkroom.Engineers.
I saw the same idea used by Edoardo Lunardi on their inspiration page. That is basically the same concept I am trying to achieve.
The problem
I've configured the Lenis plugin with the appropriate settings, and it works perfectly when the page has vertical elements. Here is a demo that I worked out.
So then I created another codepen where I positioned the slides as indicated in my concept side by side. To move the slider horizontally, when scrolling vertically, I added an addeventlistener for the wheel property.
window.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
  scrollContainer.scrollLeft += e.deltaY;
});

I have looked at the example that I uses as inspiration and I saw that it does not use transform: translate, so changing the slides is not done using GSAP if I am correctly and is done by Lenis. I came across this article and implemented the above code. This translates the vertical scroll to the horizontal change of the slider, but then I missing the smooth scroll and ease out (so it will be smooth out to the begin and ending of the page.
When I paste the same js code from Lenis as my first codepen example, the plugin isn't working. Nothing will be logged in my console that is coming from the log in the lenis.on('scroll') function. I found out that by adding the properties orientation: 'horizontal' and content: scrollContainer, makes a difference. It console log the same as in the first codepen: [Log] D {__isSmooth: true, __isScrolling: false, __isStopped: false, __isLocked: false, onVirtualScroll: function, …} (iframeConsoleRunner-6d8bf8b4b479137260842506acbb12717dace0823c023e08b96360e60b0840d9.js, line 1).
But I am missing the smoothness and it seems like the code doesn't take into account translating the vertical scroll to the horizontal, but this is just guesswork. I tried other properties as well, like gestureOrientation and smoothWheel, but with no succes.
The JS code
Here's a version of my code:
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector("main");

const lenis = new Lenis({
  orientation: 'horizontal',
  content: scrollContainer,
  // easing: (t) => Math.min(1, 1.001 - Math.pow(2, -10 * t))
});

lenis.on('scroll', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
});

function raf(time) {
  lenis.raf(time);
  requestAnimationFrame(raf);
}
requestAnimationFrame(raf);

window.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
  scrollContainer.scrollLeft += e.deltaY;
});

Slot
When looking at the official docs from Lenis and the example from Edoardo Lunardi it is something that is possible, but I missing the right thing or clue to get it work.

Try to set wrapper into lenis constructor:
const lenis = new Lenis({
  // lerp: 1,
  // wheelMultiplier: 1,
  easing: function(t){return (t === 1 ? 1 : 1 - Math.pow(2, -10 * t))},
    direction: "horizontal",
    gestureDirection: "horizontal",
  orientation: 'horizontal',
  content: scrollContainer,
  wrapper: scrollContainer
});

Or hack using this code:
import Lenis from "https://esm.sh/@studio-freight/lenis";

const scrollContainer = document.querySelector("main");

const lenis = new Lenis({
  // lerp: 1,
  // wheelMultiplier: 1,
  orientation: 'horizontal',
  content: scrollContainer,
  // easing: (t) => Math.min(1, 1.001 - Math.pow(2, -10 * t))
});

lenis.on('scroll', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
});

function raf(time) {
  lenis.raf(time);
  requestAnimationFrame(raf);
}
requestAnimationFrame(raf);


//Code ADDED

function SmoothScroll(target, speed, smooth) {
    if (target === document)
        target = (document.scrollingElement 
              || document.documentElement 
              || document.body.parentNode 
              || document.body) // cross browser support for document scrolling
      
    var moving = false
    var pos = target.scrollLeft
  var frame = target === document.body 
              && document.documentElement 
              ? document.documentElement 
              : target // safari is the new IE
  
    target.addEventListener('mousewheel', scrolled, { passive: false })
    target.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', scrolled, { passive: false })

    function scrolled(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // disable default scrolling

        var delta = normalizeWheelDelta(e)

        pos += -delta * speed
        pos = Math.max(0, Math.min(pos, target.scrollWidth - frame.clientWidth)) // limit scrolling

        if (!moving) update()
    }

    function normalizeWheelDelta(e){
        if(e.detail){
            if(e.wheelDelta)
                return e.wheelDelta/e.detail/40 * (e.detail>0 ? 1 : -1) // Opera
            else
                return -e.detail/3 // Firefox
        }else
            return e.wheelDelta/120 // IE,Safari,Chrome
    }

    function update() {
        moving = true
    
        var delta = (pos - target.scrollLeft) / smooth
    
        target.scrollLeft += delta
    
        if (Math.abs(delta) > 0.5)
            requestFrame(update)
        else
            moving = false
    }

    var requestFrame = function() { // requestAnimationFrame cross browser
        return (
            window.requestAnimationFrame ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
            function(func) {
                window.setTimeout(func, 1000 / 50);
            }
        );
    }()
}

function init(){
    new SmoothScroll(scrollContainer,120,12)
}

init()

Reference: Smooth vertical scrolling on mouse wheel in vanilla javascript?

Thank you André for sharing the solution. I tried both methods, but for both the when sliding to the beginning or end of the slider it will lag a little bit (like a small shake). I think because the code is executed multiple times? And What methode do you prefer / advice to use?

I have updated the codepen here, where in Safari it works really buggy. It jumps back and forward while scrolling. Also in the beginning sometimes it doesn't do anything when I scroll: https://codepen.io/casperlw/pen/XWQEENM?editors=1010

@Caspert awkward for me is realy smooth https://imgur.com/a/PTezmPo

I prefer the first code! You can try to play with easing function, this function will defines the animation os your scroll. Search about easing function and try to change to see different behaviors.

I think your screen record is from Chrome right? In Safari it is really buggy as you see here inside codepen: https://imgur.com/a/gVcJVY2 but also when I use the exact same code in my own project with images the problem is even more visible as you can see here: https://imgur.com/a/uWLFUxf Im not forcing the scroll, just how you would normally scroll. In Chrome it works perfectly smooth, but not in Safari. The example from above works for both Chrome and Safari. Do you've a clue how to solve this strange behavior? I think something is executed multiple times at once?

Its a problem with the library and not with the code. I suggest you to change the library or check in the library forum if you can improve it... Could you upvote the answer?
